# Can't run fine-tuning for llama 7b with LORA (OOM)

Tags: huggingface-transformers, llama, huggingface-trainer

I am trying to fine-tune llama 7b using Lora + deepseed, I hit OOM all the time (I have rtx 3090 24 GB + 32GB RAM + 80G SWAP). it looks like it doesn't offload it to CPU/RAM. I tried different parameters with diff values, but it looks it is just don't offload it and try to run it on GPU only. I spent couple of days trying to run it, pls help

> torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 172.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 23.47 GiB of which 100.38 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 21.66 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 21.40 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 11.11 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated.

```
def load_model_and_tokenizer(model_name, project_tag):
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, cache_dir="./llama")
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, cache_dir="./llama")
....

loraConfig = LoraConfig(
    r=16,
    lora_alpha=32,
    lora_dropout=0.05,
    # target_modules=lora_target_modules,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
)

project_tag = "<projectX>"
model_name = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"
model, tokenizer = load_model_and_tokenizer(model_name, project_tag)
model = prepare_model_for_int8_training(model)
model = get_peft_model(model, loraConfig)
file_path = "encodedProjectData.txt"
unlabeled_texts = read_data_from_file(file_path)
unlabeled_dataset = CustomUnlabeledDataset(unlabeled_texts, tokenizer)

training_arguments=TrainingArguments(
        auto_find_batch_size=True,
        optim="adafactor", gradient_checkpointing=True,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
        warmup_steps=2,
        max_steps=60,
        learning_rate=2e-4,
        evaluation_strategy = 'steps',
        eval_accumulation_steps = 1,
        eval_steps = 10,
        seed =  42,
        # report_to="wandb",
        fp16=True,
        logging_steps=1,
        output_dir='outputs'
    )

# Wrap the model with DeepSpeed
model, optimizer, _, _ = deepspeed.initialize(model=model, args=training_arguments, config=deepspeed_config)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=unlabeled_dataset,
    args=training_arguments,

)
trainer.train()
```

```
deepspeed_config = {
    "fp16": {
        "enabled": False
    },
    "bf16": {
        "enabled": False
    },
    "zero_optimization": {
        "stage": 3,
        "offload_param": {
            "device": "cpu",
            "pin_memory": True
        },
        "overlap_comm": True,
        "contiguous_gradients": True,
        "reduce_bucket_size": "auto"
    },
    "steps_per_print": 2000,
    "train_batch_size": 1,
    "train_micro_batch_size_per_gpu": 1,
    "wall_clock_breakdown": False
}
```

I tried different TrainingArguments and different setups to run fine tunning